# Npm audit fix --force not working. Can't use npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem with npm, when I try to install a package using npm it shows this error.

I tried to upgrade expo, reinstall expo and run `npm audit fix --force` but none of them worked.

```
qs  6.7.0 - 6.7.2
Severity: high
qs vulnerable to Prototype Pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-hrpp-h998-j3pp
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install expo@44.0.6, which is a breaking change
node_modules/qs
  body-parser  1.19.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of qs
  node_modules/body-parser
    @expo/dev-server  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of body-parser
    node_modules/@expo/dev-server
      @expo/cli  >=0.1.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/dev-server
      node_modules/@expo/cli
        expo  >=45.0.0-beta.1
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @expo/cli
        node_modules/expo

5 high severity vulnerabilities
```

Comment: Have you just tried `npm install expo@latest`?

Comment: it didn't work :/

Comment: ..what is the result of the command?

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: I don't see an error anywhere in your post. Please provide more information.

Comment: I'm trying to install expo with npm but it's finding some vulnerabilities and npm audit fix --force not working. When I try to install some other packages I get, ```while resolving: (project name) found: react@18.1.0 react@18.1.0 from the root project peer@"*" react from native-base@3.4.25 Could not resolve dependency: peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0```